# Что означает эта запись?

Tags: c++, указатели

Каким образом работает эта функция сравнения? Что значит `(int*)`?

```
int compare(const void* x1, const void* x2)
{
    return (*(int*)x1 - *(int*)x2);
}
```

Comment: На этот вопрос можно ответить целой статьей, если не книгой

Comment: Лучше верните предыдущий вариант вопроса, тот, в котором функция с  (int*), а не вопрос по применимости указателей и ссылок.

Comment: Вне конкретного контекста, это не "функция сравнения", а скорее "кривая функция сравнения", которая в общем случае НЕ работает. Сравнивать два `int` путем вычитания нельзя - может произойти переполнение и результат получится бессмысленным.

Comment: если только не учитывать переполнения, то эта функция почти классический вариант реализации компаратора для qsort, но только сишного, а не плюсового.

Comment: @KoVadim: А в чем будет отличие плюсового компаратора для `qsort`?

Comment: тем, что есть более оптимальные решения

Answer (score 4):

`(int*)` означает приведение указателя типа `void` к указателю на `int`

Далее происходит разыменование указателей (левые звездочки) и вычитание.

Обратите внимание, у Вас используются указатели на константу `const void*`. Не перепутайте с константным указателем (`const` пишется справа от звездочки).